# Как сохранить выбранные позиции Select option в файл в числовом значении

Tags: javascript, jquery

Подскажите как организовать выгрузку выбранных value значений в файл, с последовательностью 111 или 001.
Поясняю:
0 это a1
1 это b2
После того как я выберу у меня высвечивается в тэге span результат моих действий, у меня практически нету опыта с работы файлами, подскажите как мне полученные данные сохранить в файл txt например.

```
function recalculate(){
    $('#res').text('');
    var sum = 0;
    $('div').each(function(){
        var selectVal = $('select',this).val();

        $('#res').append(selectVal);
        if($(this).index() < $('div').length - 1){
            $('#res').append(' '); -- получаю value значения выбранных селектов, проблема в сохранении. Подскажите как реализовать 
        }
        sum +=selectVal * 1;
    });
    $('#res').append('<p>Согласовано: ' + sum + ' </p>');
    return;
}

$('select').change(function(){
    recalculate();
});
```

[Пример](http://jsfiddle.net/zy43gmz1/2/)

Пишу только на js или jQuery. Php в этой работе не рассматриваю.

Comment: js не работает с файлами, нужна серверная часть, сделайте её на nodejs например

Comment: а статью или с чего начать подскажите, с nodejs я совсем не знаком.

Comment: видимо не правильно вас понял, вам нужно на сервере обработать или просто пользователю скачать, если второе, то вариант предложенный в ответе вам подойдет. Если все же первый, то документаций по работе с файлами и создании простого сервера много, можете посмотреть в сторону Express на nodejs

Comment: 2 вариант, пользователь выбрал значения селектов, и в файл на клиенте сохранился  бы  файл txt с текстом внутри 111 например.

Comment: Используете метод с низу, генерируете данные например `var data = 'Hello from App'`, и вызываете метод `download(data, 'customFileName', 'text')`, вам скачается файл с текстом `Hello from App` и имя файла будет `customFileName`

Comment: попробовал написать, поправьте пожалуйста у меня не работает https://jsfiddle.net/z5pwht3g/2/

Comment: Ну видимо стоит вынести вызов функции из тела самой функции(вынести за `}`) `download(data, 'customFileName', 'text');`. И пройтись по литературе по JS тоже не помешало бы \*sigh\*

Comment: @Элиот почитайте что такое функции и как они вызываются. Зачем вы пытаетесь делать вещи, которые требуют знаний, без знаний? Вы вызвали функцию в своей функции, создав рекурсию, НО, сам метод `download` вы не вызвали ни разу. Вам правильно подсказал `SLy_huh`

Answer (score 0):

```
// Function to download data to a file
function download(data, filename, type) {
    var a = document.createElement("a"),
    file = new Blob([data], {type: type});
    if (window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) // IE10+
        window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(file, filename);
    else { // Others
        var url = URL.createObjectURL(file);
        a.href = url;
        a.download = filename;
        document.body.appendChild(a);
        a.click();
        setTimeout(function() {
            document.body.removeChild(a);
            window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);  
        }, 0); 
    }
}
```

[Подобный тред на SO.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13405129/javascript-create-and-save-file), заняло около 2х секунд гуглинга.